# AppleScript can not show CJK characters from environment variables correctly

Tags: bash, variables, syntax, applescript, osascript

AppleScript has no problem dealing with UTF-8 characters inside the script. But it is unable to retrieve UTF-8 characters correctly from the environment variables.

`osascript -e 'do shell script "echo " &"你好"'`

> 你好

`HELLO=你好 osascript -e 'do shell script "echo "& (system attribute "HELLO")'`

> ‰Ω†Â•Ω

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `system attribute` doesn’t respect the shell environment’s `LANG`. Eh, they’re both ancient and nasty.

This will give you the right value:

```
HELLO=你好 osascript -e 'do shell script "echo \"$HELLO\""'
# 你好
```

Alternatively, use `NSUserDefaults` via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge. I wrote a bunch of [AppleScript libraries](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib) a few years back; the `File` library’s `environment variables` command uses this approach.

Comment: This is quite limited in its usage as it only works when retrieving UTF8 characters from the environment variables if used with `do shell script`. Lets consider the following works when using `system attribute`; e.g. `HELLO=foo osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog system attribute "HELLO"'`. However it fails when using  UTF8; e.g. `HELLO=你好 osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog system attribute "HELLO"'` _(i.e. dialog displays `‰Ω†Â•Ω`)_. So, as per this answer, the following doesn't work: `HELLO=你好 osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog \"$HELLO\"'`

Comment: However, you can set the result of `echo` in the  `do shell script` to an AppleScript variable before using elsewhere in subsequent `osascript` commands. For example, the following correctly displays `你好` in the dialog:  `HELLO=你好 osascript -e 'set envVar to do shell script "echo \"$HELLO\""' -e  'tell app "Finder" to display dialog envVar'`